# Rendering WebControl with Empty Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to build a control that derives from `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl` that allows 'empty' attributes?

I.e. I need to output `<div helloworld></div>`

Ive tried overriding `RenderEndTag()` and `this.Attributes.Add("helloworld",null)` and neither work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looked a bit deeper, the following code works;

```
protected override void AddAttributesToRender(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
   writer.AddAttribute("helloworld", null);
}
```

Reflecting `System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter.RenderBegin()` midway down where attributes are written shows the line:

```
...
this.writer.Write(' ');
this.writer.Write(renderAttribute.name);
if (renderAttribute.value != null)
{
this.writer.Write("=\"");
...
```

Which shows why the above works, and `this.Attributes.Add` doesn't (I believe a filter is run to exclude any null attribute values).

Answer (score 0):

No. The syntax used for control parsing in ASP.NET web forms requires that attributes must have a value.

The best you could do is to use inner content:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" id="fooLabel" Text="Hello, world!"/>
```

is the same as

```
<asp:Label runat="server" id="fooLabel">Hello, world!</asp:Label>
```